# FCM, Notification-type message, how to group like Gmail?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When multiple mails arrive one by one, Gmail groups them and shows only one notification message on the Notification Area. I would like to do the same thing. I searched Google and found that I need to set `tag`, but setting the same `tag` just replaced the previous one, not showing multiple messages as Gmail.

Should I not use the notification-type, but use the data-type only and handle notifications myself? If so, this should be something a lot of people are ding. Is there a sample project that I can start with?

Also, if I can somehow use the notification-type for grouping, it gives the data as Intent extras. How does it pass multiple data to my activity, if the notification is showing multiple items as Gmail?

```
{
  "to": "/topics/that",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Title 686",
    "body": "My body",
    "tag": "xxx"
  },
  "data": {
    "title": "Title 686",
    "body": "My body",
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inbox style with notification builder

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_glyph)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentText(contentText);

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                inboxStyle.addLine(("Message " + i);
            }
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
            mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
```

Comment: Does this mean that I should not use `notification` and use only `data`, and then create the notification myself? The point of my question was not how I could create a customised notification like that, but how to get the effect with the FCM `notification`, which creates a notification automatically.